# styling a company logo and text with simple HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to put my company logo and text side by side using simple HTML. I dont want to use flexbox. I tried this in order to achieve it :

```html
  <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    <img src="logo.png" height="80" width="80" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name1">This is some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name2">This is some text1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This is what I see with above HTML:

[image]

This is the style sheet:

```
<style>
  .name1 {
            font-size: 25px;
            color: #e9c46a;
           
        }

        .name2 {
            font-size: 25px;
            color: white;
        }
</style>
```

Everything looks good except, I want to reduce the space between logo and text. How can I do that. I cannot use flexbox.

Comment: **a:** I'd suggest that [CSS grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) would be better than flex (if you're at all able to use grid, but given the antipathy to flex, I suspect probably not), and **b:** why are you using a `<table>` for layout? If you use almost any other elements with in an appropriate wrapper element, you could just use `float`.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use flexbox? (Is it because you just don't want to or a requirement to support older devices, this is important because it might rule out other solutions as well) because normnaly `<table>` should not be used for layout anymore but only for tabular content.

Comment: requirement to support older devices. I can use float. can you help me with float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a  `width="80"` HTML attribute to the leftmost `td` you have so the size of the `td` will fit the size of the logo `img`.

```html
<table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" width="80">
                    <img src="logo.png" height="80" width="80" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name1">This is some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name2">This is some text1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **`translateX`** CSS Property:

Here I added the class `logo` to the image so I can apply the CSS property to it.

```css
.logo {
  transform: translateX(15vw);
}

.name1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #e9c46a;
}

.name2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;padding:10px">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <img src="logo.png" height="80" width="80" class="logo" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name1">This is some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name2">This is some text1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Check [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) that explains 2d transforms.

Link to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d)

Comment: I tried your code above transform: translateX(2em); The space is still there.

Comment: Using the transform: `translateX()` property doesn't remove the space since it only moves the image element horizontally. This property doesn't take into account the distance between other elements, for that you would need to make it dynamic/responsive. Example: 33vw - 80px (subtract the size of the image from a thrid of the size of the viewport width)

Answer (score 0):

To specify where content should be display in your td
You can use attributed valign and align
for example like

```
<td valign="top" align="right">
<img src="yourImage">
</td>
```

valign determine vertical position
and
align determine horizontal position

Comment: This moved the logo all the way to the right

Comment: Isn't that what you want to obtain?
If you need stace between them you should add another td with width coresponding to space which you want to stay empty like 
<td><img><td/>
<td width="20"></td>
<td>your text</td>

Note that attribute width is in pixel by default if you want use rem then give it in style attribute